# localstorage not defined in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage

im trying to move an application from React to Next

In React I get no error on this code

```
let [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(() => localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)

let [user, setUser] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)
```

but when I try to use it in Next, I get the error

[image: localStorage is not defined]

Which I assume is because Next is rendering on server side first and theres no local storage on server side.

This is the function that's setting the local storage.

```
let loginUser = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'email':e.target.username.value, 'password':e.target.password.value})
        })
        let data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        console.log(data.access)
        if(response.status == 200) {
            setAuthTokens(data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(data.access))
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(data))
            router.push('/')
        } else {
            alert('something went wrong')
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are you calling loginUser method, is it on the client-side or server-side.

Comment: @RajneeshChaurasia its client side, triggered by a submit button on a form

Comment: is the issue happens on the first render or after submitting the form???

Comment: @devAR Next.js [pre-renders every page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering) on the server, which means Web APIs, like `localStorage`, are not available. You have to move any client-side only code inside a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed it by moving the logic from the useState and moving it in a useEffect

Instead of having

```
let [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(() => localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)

let [user, setUser] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)
```

I moved the logic in useEffect like so

```
let [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(null)
let [user, setUser] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        
            if(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) {
                setAuthTokens(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')))
                setUser(jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')))
            } else {
                setAuthTokens(null)
                setUser(null)
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

When your application renders on the server, there are no `browser` APIs there.
What you need to do is to access the `localStorage` only when the app is rendered in the browser. You can do that by waiting for the component to be mounted and then accessing the `localStorage`

```js
function MyComponent(){
  // this runs only in the browser
  useEffect(()=>{
  // access local storage here
  },[])
}
```

Comment: Do I put the useSates inside the useEffect(which i dont think you can) because in the error, its pointing to the useStates. updated with a pic

Comment: You can't put `localStorage` in `useState` (there is no `localStorage` when `useState` runs)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
   if(response.status == 200) {
            setAuthTokens(data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(data.access))
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(data))
            router.push('/')
        } else {
            alert('something went wrong')
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it to something dummy or blank inside `useState`. Use `useEffect` to set it once the app is mounted.

Note that your existing setAuthTokens function will be working normally inside the loginUser function without any changes required.

Answer (score -1):

Inside `useState`, you can check if window is not undefined before accessing local storage. You can do something like this

```
let [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(
  () => typeof window !== "undefined" 
    ? localStorage.getItem('authTokens') 
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) 
        : null)
```

Comment: There are missing parts to this code. There are seemingly two conditional operators, yet there is only one `? :` and then one `?` without a `?`.